# Dispatch on main queue, type issues?

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I've been using this code successfully for a few months:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // do something                   
});
```

but in a new target I get a warning that `dispatch_get_main_queue` returns a `dispatch_queue_s` when in fact I need a `dispatch_queue_t`. However, the code works.

**Is this a problem? If so, what is the easiest solution?**

Comment: What iOS/Xcode versions?

Comment: Is it just `dispatch_get_main_queue`?

Comment: @BoA In my experience, that should work without warnings.

Comment: Sorry: the warnings are coming from AppCode. Now I'd delete the question, but it's already been upvoted. However, I still don't know why this works or doesn't work, so it's a valid question. But Xcode does not warn.

Comment: @BoA yes, it's just that dispatch that returns the wrong type for dispatch_async